# Remove elements from a list C

Tags: c

I have done this code to remove an element from a list:

List structure:

```
typedef struct list_t{
  struct node_t *head;
  int size;
};

typedef struct node_t{
  struct entry_t *element;//Each entry has a key
  struct node_t *next;
}node_t;
```

Remove method:

```
int list_remove(struct list_t *list, char *key){
  node_t *no = list->head;
  struct list_t *lista = list_create();
  int i;
  for(i=0;i<list->size;i++){
    if(strcmp(no->element->key, key)==0)
      no=no->next;
    else {
      list_add(lista,no->element);
      no=no->next;
    }
  }
}
```

Each element on the list has a key.

My idea was to create a new list (lista) with the elements from the given list (list) except the element I want to remove.

My problem now is:

1. How can I remove all the elements from the old list (list)?
2. How can I add the elements from the new list (lista) to old list (list)?

Thanks.

Comment: Just think it through, very carefully.  And think again when your first attempt doesn't work.  Dealing with lists is *very* tricky, and attempting to just "patch" your way to a correct scheme will never work.

Comment: (BTW, you're declaring `no` twice.)

Comment: Why can't you just delete the node in-place in the same list. Why use another list?

Comment: I have tried with the same list, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @TiagoSantos can you post the structure details of the node. Maybe we can help you then!!

Comment: When dealing with linked lists, it can be very helpful to draw diagrams. You want to draw what the list will look like before and after the deletion for each case: deleted item is head of list, in the middle of the list, tail of list, the only item in the list, list is empty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the standard way to delete a node in a linked list, in-place. Hopefully this should work for you:

```
int list_remove(struct list_t *list, char *key) {
  node_t *node = list->head;
  node_t *prev = NULL;   //to keep track of the previous node
  int i;
  for(i=0; i<list->size; i++) {
    if(strcmp(node->element->key, key)==0) {
      if(node == list->head) {   //if 1st node has to be deleted
        if(list->size == 1)    //if there's only one node in list
          list->head = NULL;
        else
          list->head = node->next;
        list->size--;
        return 0;
      }
      prev->next = node->next;
      return 0;
    } else {
      prev = node;
      node=node->next;
    }
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Look,

you don't have to create a new list for this, it's not efficient at all!

First, you have to check if the element is the first one!

If you want to deleate the i'th chain, go to the (i-1) element and connect it with the (i+1) and then free the i'th element.